# How to retrieve analytics data from facebook real time?

Tags: google-analytics, statistics, analytics, facebook-analytics

I wanted to integrate the analytical system into my application so the admin can view all the analytics on the admin portal of my application.
I tried lots of web analytics tools including [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics) and [Facebook Analytics](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/analytics/). And they are storing custom analytics very well but the problem is I am not able to find any way to retrieve this data so I can display it on my admin portal. I searched a lot but I am not sure if they provide any endpoint to retrieve data.

I Stucked into this for so long and need some proper solution for it, any other analytical tool will also work, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the [Google Analytics Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples#python_8)?

Another possible solution is to create a data dump with [BigQuery](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9823238). I think you must upgrade from universal analytics to Google Analytics 4(GA4) because BigQuery was previously only available for Google Analytics 360 (enterprise) accounts.

Real-time gathering of data is not possible because GA aggregates the data first before it is available. So it would be wise if you thought of exporting the data once a day.

I think Facebook also grants the option to export data, but I'm not really familiar with it.

Comment: The Realtime method of the Google Analytics Data API offers reports for the last 30 minutes of event data. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/realtime-basics